# Retrieving a URL from Facebook app

Tags: facebook, url

Is it possible to get the URL of a post from the Facebook app and copy it to the clipboard? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

only way is to open the link in browser and copy the link from the address bar.

Comment: This is not an answer to what he asked.